# Grunt.js templates: Use the name of the target in a task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm trying to use the name of the target in a template. Should be simple enough, right?

My scenario is this:

```
copy:
{
  all: {
    src: 'commonFiles/**', dest: 'build/<%= grunt.???? =>/common'
  },
  apple: { ... },
  orange:{ ... },
  banana:{ ... },
  ...
}

grunt.registerTask('default', ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']);

grunt.registerTask('apple' ,  'copy:all copy:apples ... ... ...');
grunt.registerTask('orange',  'copy:all copy:orange ... ... ...');
grunt.registerTask('banana',  'copy:all copy:banana ... ... ...');
grimt.registerTask(...);
...
many, many more fruit
```

I've scoured the docs, I've console.log'd `grunt` but found no string that is the parent task. The closest I found was `grunt.task.current.name` but that ends up being `copy:all`.

The goal would be to get a directory structure like this for all my fruit:

```
build/apple/common/...
build/orange/common/...
build/banana/common/...
build/.../common/...
...
commonFiles/...
```

I'm sending a fruit basked to whomever can figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

A dynamic alias task would probably be better suited for this use case.
See http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#dynamic-alias-tasks

```
grunt.initConfig({
  buildDir: 'all',
  copy: {
    all: {
      src: 'commonFiles/**',
      dest: 'build/<%= buildDir =>/common',
    },
    apple: { ... },
    orange:{ ... },
    banana:{ ... },
  },
});

grunt.registerTask('build', function(target) {
  if (target == null) {
    return grunt.warn('Build target must be specified, like build:apple.');
  }
  grunt.config('buildDir', target);
  grunt.task.run('copy:' + target);
});
```

Comment: Sort of on the right track, but grunt.config doesn't seem to change if called multiple times.

http://pastebin.com/15zkPeGg

Comment: Im suggesting just create one alias task instead of a bunch of tasks since you want dynamic names. `grunt build:apple`, `grunt build:orange`, etc.

`grunt.task.run` queues a task to run in a series... so calling `grunt.config` between wont work. My example sets the config, queues the task to run, then upon the `build` task finishing, will run that  queued task with the designated config.